# Schubert Calculus for the Full Flags

Tags: cohomology, grassmannians, flag-varieties, enumerative-geometry, schubert-calculus

Almost all introductory texts on Schubert calculus discuss the Grassmannian case only. Does there exist a nice discussion of the full flag manifold case $SU(N)/T^{N-1}$? A low dimensional example along the lines of this excellent [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196546/hard-lefschetz-theorem-for-the-flag-manifolds) would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at Part III of Fulton's "Young tableaux"?

Comment: You can take a look of Michel Brion' lecture note on flag variety

Comment: The general case, for every type, is developed by Borel, "Sur la cohomologie ...", Kostant and Bernstein-Gelfand-Gelfand, "Schubert Cells and Cohomology of the Spaces $G/P$".  Of course that is not the end of the story: for many purposes the general method is inefficient or insufficient for some other purpose (e.g., description of the quantum cohomology rather than just the cohomology).