# The dimension of the Grassmannian cohomology ring $H^*(\mathrm{Gr}_{n,d})$ and the fundamental $\frak{sl}_n$-representation $V_{\pi_d}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, grassmannians, schubert-calculus

The vector space dimension of the cohomology group of the $2$-plane Grassmannian $\mathrm{Gr}_{2,n}$ is given by the number of tuples $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ satisfying
$$
n - 2 \geq \lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq 0.
$$
Explicitly this is given by
$$
\binom{n}{2}.
$$
This also happens to be the dimension of $V_{\pi_2}$ the second fundamental representation of $\frak{sl}_n$. I am guessing this is not an accident, especially since the $2$-plane Grassmannian corresponds (in the usual way) to $V_{\pi_2}$.

Does this extend to the general identity
$$
\mathrm{dim}(H^{*}(\mathrm{Gr}_{d,n})) =  \mathrm{dim}(V_{\pi_d})?
$$
If it does, then what is a conceptual explanation for this?

EDIT: Since $V_{\pi_d}$ is isomorphic to the exterior power
$$
\Lambda^d(V_{\pi_1})
$$
and $V_{\pi_1}$ is of dimension of $n$, we see that the RHS of the claimed identity is the binomial coefficient
$$
\binom{n}{d}.
$$
It follows from the general formula given in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196546/hard-lefschetz-theorem-for-the-flag-manifolds) that the LHS is the same binomial coefficient. Thus the identity does indeed extend from $2$-planes to $d$-planes. So the question is if there is a conceptual reason for this . . .

Comment: Yes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Weil%E2%80%93Bott_theorem

Comment: @Sam The Borel-Weil theorem relates the space of holomorphic sections of a line bundle to $\frak{g}$-representations. I am asking about the dimension of the Schubert calculus algebra (i.e. the cohomology group of the whole untwisted de Rham complex).

Comment: Ah of course sorry I was mixing up the coordinate ring and the cohomology ring. Still, I think it may be a starting point...

Comment: @Sam Ok, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The best explanation I know of the relation between Grassmannian cohomology and representations of SL_n is this paper of Tamvakis: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306414

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is very standard. For a compact complex variety admitting a cell decomposition, the (co)homology is the free Abelian group generated by the cells (over $\mathbb{C}$ there is no room for the differential in the cellular complex). In the cellular decomposition of the Grassmannian, the (Schubert) cells are indexed by possible reduced row echelon forms of a $d\times n$-matrix, that is by possible positions of pivots. To the cell having pivots in positions $i_1,\ldots,i_d$ you can assign the basis element $e_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{i_d}$ in $\Lambda^d(V_{\pi_1})$.

Comment: Is there a conceptual explanation for the relation with this dimension and the dimension of the linear part of the coordinate ring?

Comment: @SamHopkins well, "the coordinate ring" is something that is not as well defined as the cohomology - you are presumably talking about the coordinate ring of the Plücker embedding - so your question is why the Plücker embedding exists, or not?

Comment: I suppose so, yes.

Comment: @SamHopkins here is a speculative idea. Coordinates of the Plücker embedding should separate different points. If we wish that the embedding is defined in a universal way, we perhaps should wish that it separates points over $\mathbb{F}_1$, which naively makes one think that the number of coordinates should be given by the number of $\mathbb{F}_1$-points, that is $\binom{n}{d}$. Someone who is well versed in geometry over $\mathbb{F}_1$ can say if this can be made rigorous, but as a heuristics I certainly find it rather useful.

Comment: Do you know of some nice natural way of defining a structure of an irreducible $\mathfrak {sl}_n$-module on this ring? AFAICT, the standard action induced from the Grassmannian is trivial. (Not sure if this was part of the question but kinda curious.)

Comment: @IgorMakhlin the ring is graded, and the $sl_n$ action is going to mess it up, so something non-trivial will have to happen. I don't know what it could be.

Comment: @Vladimir One can find papers such as [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.08754) or [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.03824) that seem to consider actions where root vectors act as derivations of the cohomology ring which shift the grading. This is kind of what I had in mind, not that I claim to have made sense of either paper.

Comment: @IgorMakhlin - interesting! I was not aware of these papers. Particularly https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.08754 might be a good candidate for a conceptual answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Names of papers from @IgorMakhlin's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440744/the-dimension-of-the-grassmannian-cohomology-ring-h-mathrmgr-n-d-and-t#comment1137223_440753):  [Nhok Tkhai Shon Ngo - $\operatorname{GL}_n$-structure and principal $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple on the cohomology ring of complex Grassmannian](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.08754); [Gatto and Salehyan  - The Cohomology of the Grassmannian is a $\mathit{gl}_n$-module](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.03824).

Answer (score 8):

Harry Tamvakis gives an explanation of the relation between Grassmannian cohomology and representations of SL_n in [The connection between representation theory and Schubert calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306414).

One fundamental obstacle for explaining this phenomenon is that there is not an analogous relationship between the cohomology rings of other flag varieties (Grassmannian-analogues for other Lie groups) and the representations of those Lie groups. For Tamvakis, the key fact that makes his explanation go is that GL_n is dense in its own Lie algebra, which is not generally true for other Lie groups. (At least this is what I remember; it's been a while since I read the paper carefully.)

Answer (score 7):

This is a special case of geometric Satake.  I have to admit, I'm really struggling to find a place where this theorem is stated in an elementary-ish statement that makes this clear and am totally failing.  By [Mirkovic-Vilonen, Thm. 7.3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0401222.pdf) (and the discussion below), the irreps $V_{\lambda}$ of any complex algebraic group can be written as the intersection cohomology of the closure $\overline{\check{G}[[t]] \cdot t^{\lambda}\cdot  \check{G}[[t]]}/G[[t]]\subset G((t))/G[[t]]$ in the affine Grassmannian.  If $\lambda$ is minuscule, then this orbit is already closed and smooth, so the intersection cohomology is usual cohomology.  Furthermore, it is of the form $\check{G}/\check{P}$ for $\check{P}$ the parabolic corresponding to the stabilizer of the minuscule weight in the Weyl group.

For $G=\check{G}=GL_n$, these are all Grassmannians; more generally, every minuscule representation is isomorphic to the cohomology of the corresponding cominuscule flag variety of the dual group.

Comment: In your last paragraph, what category is that isomorphism happening in?

Comment: @Oliver They are isomorphic as vector spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I accidentally (looking for something else) came across another paper where a very elegant explanation is given:

[Dan Laksov, Anders Thorup: Schubert Calculus on Grassmannians and Exterior Powers](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24903230)

Indiana University Mathematics Journal, Vol. 58, No. 1 (2009), pp. 283-300

They introduce the "$d$-th factorization algebra" that "controls" the ways to factor a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ into a product of factors of degrees $d$ and $n-d$, relate the $d$-th exterior power of the quotient by $p(x)$ to the $d$-th factorization algebra (Main Theorem, see Sec.0.6), and also relate the $d$-th factorization algebra to the Schubert calculus (Sections 4 and 5).